# Install some Windows Updates automatically - Filter Rules?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Is there a way to install some Windows Updates (those that don't nag about rebooting, especially the Windows Defender Definitions) automatically without asking and the rest when I tell them to?

I'm thinking of something like Filters in an E-Mail Client: Match against some user defined rules and perform actions on them.

Are there any settings in Windows or tools that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run gpedit.msc, the local group policy editor.

Navigate to Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Windows Update.

There is a policy (on the right) called **Allow Automatic Updates immediate installation**. Double click this policy and enable it.

Comment: Not the generic solution I wished for, but it does its job. Once there, I also found "No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations" which also sounds useful. Let's see if they can keep their promises.

Comment: Agreed. Like most built-in functionality, it's not great but passable.